# Trouble with .htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I hope below mentioned condition in my .htaccess which works perfectly fine. I want to add a similar condition but when I do, it ignores that continues to use this one.

Currently in .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item.php?country=%1&adid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Want to add :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^redirect/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ redirect.php?country=%1&item=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want pk.domain.com/redirect/242/ to go to redirect.php and give following $_REQUEST values

1. Country = pk
2. Item = 242

Instead of going to redirect.php it goes to item.php.

Secondly my website fails URL Canonicalization Test.

- http://pk.domain.com

and

- http://www.pk.domain.com/ should resolve to the same URL, but currently do not.

Any help with these two issues would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For the second case, do you mean, you want to redirect all requests for `http://pk.domain.com` to `http://www.pk.domain.com`?

Comment: Well for SEO supposedly thats how it should be.

Answer (score 2):

First, to permanently redirect all requests from http://pk.domain.com to http://www.pk.domain.com, you can use `RedirectMatch` in the vhost configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName pk.domain.com
        RedirectMatch permanent "/(.*)" http://www.pk.domain.com/$1
    ....
    ....
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.pk.domain.com
    ....
        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you are sure that all requests are redirected to www.pk.domain.com, you should create a .htaccess file with the following lines in the DocumentRoot for www.pk.domain.com :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^redirect/([0-9]*)/$ redirect.php?country=%1&item=$1 [L,QSA]
```

From the RewriteCond directive, the country code will be extracted in `%1` and will be available in the query string parameter `country`.

From the RewriteRule directive, the value after the string redirect/"number" will be extracted in `$1` and will be available in query string parameter `item`

**Edit** If you cannot edit the vhost configuration file, place the following in the .htaccess file under the DocumentRoot to permanently redirect all requests from  http://pk.domain.com to http://www.pk.domain.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =pk.domain.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pk.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I suggest you should first deal with the domain level redirection. Then change the configuration in .htaccess file. As in the end you want the end users to only access the domain www.pk.domain.com. The above mentioned .htaccess configuration will only be applied for www.pk.domain.com. It won't work for pk.domain.com.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I am not quite sure how to make vhost file as I haven't done before. I tried googling and it said that I should have an apache folder in my etc folder which I don't. My hosting comes with cpanel if that helps.

Comment: I have added an alternative solution to handle the domain level redirection.